# How to avoid reply from the server if user does not input anything into the form

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my code for the form and jquery code:

```
 <div id="mini">
 <p><span class="italics">Please complete the form</span></p>
 <fieldset>
<form id="appForm" onsubmit="askServer();return false;">
 <label for="Name">Name </label> <br>
 <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Han Solo" > <br>
 <label for="e-mail"> Email</label> <br>
 <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@uiowa.edu" > <br> 
 <label for ="Birthdate">Birth Date</label><br>
 <input name="bday" id="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">        
 </fieldset><br>
 <input class="btn-style" type="submit" value="Submit Application">
 </form>
     <p id="Sreply"></p>
     <script>
      function askServer() {

 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var sname=document.getElementById("name").value;
  var semail=document.getElementById("email").value;
 var sbirth=document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
 var url = "submit.php";
 var params = "?name="+sname+"&email="+semail+"&bday="+sbirth;
 var url = url+params;
 http.open("GET", url, true);

 //Send the proper header information along with the request
 http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-  urlencoded");
 http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
 http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the   state changes.
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("Sreply").innerHTML = " "+      http.responseText;
   }
   }
   http.send(params);
    }
    </script>
     </div>
```

So the problem is when i click on submit application, with blank fields I still get a reply. Is there a legit way to avoid this?And here is the link to my [Website](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~ckovuri/Lab7/lab7.html). I know adding a 'required' in the form for name,email and date would avoid it, but is there any other way?

Comment: do not submit the form if empty

Comment: I suppose have validation on the client side and do not submit the form.

Comment: I can add "required" to name and email address and birthday, but is there a more clean way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to handle this is to check the form with client-side Javascript for general validity, inform the user the form is incomplete and then don't submit it to the server.

You will still need to validate all form elements on the server when received in case client-side checks were bypassed, but that should not be the usual case.

And, you need to stop the default submission of your form also with `e.preventDefault()` in the submit handler.

```
<script>
    function askServer(e) {
        // prevent submission of the form except via the Ajax call
        e.preventDefault();
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var sname = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var semail = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var sbirth = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
        if (sname && semail && sbirth) {
            var url = "submit.php";
            var params = "?name=" + sname + "&email=" + semail + "&bday=" + sbirth;
            url = url + params;
            http.open("GET", url, true);
            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-  urlencoded");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            http.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the   state changes.
                if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("Sreply").innerHTML = " " + http.responseText;
                }
            }
            http.send(params);
        } else {
            // show some sort of error indication to the user here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put an if check in javascript itself,

```
var sname=document.getElementById("name").value;
  var semail=document.getElementById("email").value;
 var sbirth=document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
if(sname === "" && semail === "" && sbirth === ""){
// do not send the request and inform the user that form is empty
}
else{
//rest of the code
}
```